# Test coverage showing some branches missing

Tags: android, android-testing, test-coverage

I am running `gradlew app:testCoverage` on my project. Everything counts fine, except this case, I can't figure out what exactly are these *4 branches* one of which is missing. I can see only 2 cases here - exception **is** `null` and exception **is not** `null`.

[image: Exception]

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the missing case is so called "double failure".
It means the case "fail in `try` block, go to `finally` block, fail in `finally block`".
Will investigate how to cover that.